# How to read mule project version?

Tags: java, maven, mule

I have a requirement to read mule project version and return it to client. Below is pom.xml file of my mavenised mule poject.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

.
.
.
</project>
```

I want to read above version value (1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) from pom file.

Can someone please help on this? How could I get the project version in a recommended way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ${pom.version} in a filtered variable so you can retrieve it in a property file.

Imagine a file src/main/resources/version.properties which contains:
version=${pom.version}

Then you can use a Properties object:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/version.properties");
final String version = p.getProperty("version");
```

Comment: Hi 
I have tried this but I am getting different value '20030108'. I am not getting actual project version. I have added below filter in <build> element of pom file.
<resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>
  </resources>

Comment: Any idea why I am getting '20030108' as version?

Comment: I am able to see in classes/version.properties version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. But When read the 'version' property as you said its coming as '20030108'. Am not understanding whats wrong.

Comment: Maybe because another /version.properties exists in the classpath and overrides your file. Try with a different file name, like /my/version.properties ou /my-version.properties

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven I suppose tour application will include the version in its name, something like mule-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Use Mule Expression Language to extract the application name (app.name) as explained here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule%2BExpression%2BLanguage
Then extract the version from the name using a regex and return the value using an http inbound endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to pom file? or .zip file from mule?

If you have access to pom.xml file is easy get the version.

You need Unmarshalling functionality:

1.- Create a bean called "project" with groupId, artifactId, etc and **version** attributes (setters and getters of course).

2.- Parse pom.xml to project bean using unmarshall functionality :

http://lstierneyltd.com/blog/development/examples/java-to-xml-xml-to-java-marshalling-and-unmarshalling/

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
File f = new File("pom.xml");
Project project = (Project) u.unmarshal(f);
```

3.- Just get the version attribute:

```
System.out.println(project.getVersion());
```

Regards.